# Allow $wpdb mysql query to deal with specific WordPress category

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I've written the following mysql query that allows to fill the php array with the content of cells that contain specific combination of words while skipping all other cells:

```
$variable = "value";
$query = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT post_content
    FROM wp_posts
    WHERE post_content
    REGEXP '>(.*) $variable (.*)<'
");
```

It successfully meet its commitments unless I want to limit its obligations by specific WordPress category or set of WordPress categories.

At this point I just don't know how to modify my query to meet my needs.

There are tons of working examples of performing mysql queries over specific WordPress category only, but they all immediately fail to fill the array as soon as I add `REGEXP '>(.*) $variable (.*)<'` to them.

I would really use `$array = array('s' => $value, 'cat' => ID, 'posts_per_page' => -1);` or something like this if `'s'` wouldn't utilize mysql's `LIKE` statement which produces unpredictable results in my case.

Help me to modify my query, please.

If you are going to help me out with this matter I would say additional thank you in case you won't find it boring to comment every change or addition to my query, right in code near your additions. It is always great to get the ready result but I want to learn and prevent myself from asking the same questions again and again each time I face the similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

After some researches I've ended up with this working solution:

```
$variable = "value";
$query = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT ID, post_content
    FROM $wpdb->posts p
        JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships tr ON (p.ID = tr.object_id)
        JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy tt ON (tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id)
        JOIN $wpdb->terms t ON (tt.term_id = t.term_id)
        WHERE post_content REGEXP '>(.*) $variable (.*)<'
        AND tt.taxonomy = 'category'
        AND t.term_id = '###'
");
```

The last line of the query is the place where I should replace `###` with the desired WordPress category ID number.